# Postgres - how can I restrict the privilege to create/drop a table?

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I would like to create "read-only privileges" in a PostgreSQL database (including the restriction of creating or dropping tables).

My strategy is to create a group with these privileges and then add roles that have had all their privileges revoked.  In that way, the only inherit privileges when part of the read-only group.

I used the following commands to create privileges but it seems roles can add, delete tables when they join the group:

```
role_test_db=# REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE role_test_db FROM select_access_group;
REVOKE
role_test_db=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE role_test_db TO select_access_group;
GRANT
role_test_db=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO select_access_group;
GRANT
```

I was reading the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-priv.html) and it seems like creating tables would be under CREATE privilege but I have not granted this.  Can some explain why users part of this group can still make tables?

Comment: I will try this - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/why-is-a-new-user-allowed-to-create-a-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes:

1. Revoking privileges on the database does not restrict user's rights to create objects. For that, you have to revoke privileges on the schemas.
2. You can only `REVOKE` privileges that were `GRANT`ed (by default or explicitly). I doubt that `select_access_group` has ever been granted any privileges on the database.

You likely forgot to revoke the dangerous default `CREATE` privilege on schema `public`. Connect as superuser and run

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Comment: This was it - thank you. So if I want to do this default for future roles I should use 

"ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public REVOKE FROM ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;"
"REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE example_database FROM public;"?

Is there anything else?

Comment: No, you connect to `template1` and revoke the privilege there. `CREATE DATABASE` just copies the template.

Answer (score 1):

A user can only revoke privileges that were granted directly by that user

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-revoke.html

See privileges

1. \du
2. select * from pg_roles;

Change (base) prilileges under admin role (postgres)

Comment: I see thanks, so I should use superuse - my admin to change base privileges of roles and groups?