I want to create a role with permission for SLUD only
I want to create a role for connecting with the back-end, and I want it to only have select, insert, update, and delete permissions to prevent SQL injection.
I use this script:
ALTER ROLE "SIUD" WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;  

REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM "SIUD";  

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "SIUD";  

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO "SIUD";

This successfully prevents the creation or dropping of databases and roles, but I can still create and drop tables. How can I prevent the creation or dropping of tables?

Restricting permissions doesn't prevent SQL injection, but it might lessen the potential damage from such attacks. Does [https://stackoverflow.com/a/67767143/20151367] help resolve the issue?

Yes, it was helpful, and I solved it. Thank you.
